# Relation between divided table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to figure out what's the best solution in case when I want to create two tables, one of them would store `user_id` and columns such as `name`, `address` etc. and second table would be used just to store login and password data.

My idea so far is to create login table without primary key. I could use foreign key referenced to `user_id` in first table and cascade relation on update/delete so data in each tables would stay related. But I'm concerned my solution isn't good. Do you have better ideas? By the way I'm not into indexes concept yet so could you help me with that too?

Comment: Why you need to have `login` in different table? Each `user` must have 1 `login` (not more)? Also the table without `primary key` is not a good practice. What will be your DBMS?

Comment: I use MySQL. I thought it's a good practise to divide login/password stuff from 'business'. Well I parse login/password data only once, when user tries to sign in and 'business' data almost all the time.

Comment: I mean that you can store data in one table and retrieve only necessary info. You can set a field like `login_active` to disable `login` when needed. You can also set `user_active` if it is necessary. In general try not to overcomplicated things unless it is necessary. Also be careful. You must prevent your App from `SQL injection attacks`. I think that was the case in which you need to split that data. You need also take into account if there will be users (not App users) with access to your DB, which must have access to that table, but not allowed to see logins.

Comment: Big thanks to you. Btw how can I make things you mentioned in las sentence?

Comment: I mean that if you have employees that can access directly DB but are not allowed to see users `logon data` in that case you need to divide the table or set specific permissions on the column level (if it is possible). You can also write a `view` in which there are all columns except sensitive info or write a small web page to allow management of all data except `logon info`. In genereal there are a lot to read :). Your question is too broad - like *"teach me to write"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of Thumb:  If you have a pair of tables that are in a 1:1 relationship, then you have probably designed it wrong.

There are exceptions for performance where vertical partitioning is warranted, but your case is not such.

There are multiple ways to "hide" columns:

- Vertical partitioning (as you suggested) together with permissions on tables
- Permissions on columns
- `VIEWs`, together with permissions on tables and views.
- API code (PHP, etc) and not even letting non-admin users to write SQL statements.

I prefer the last option.

Passwords should be stored via a salted+encrypted one-way hash.  Then, if they are exposed accidentally, the password is not compromised.

As for `FOREIGN KEYs`, I prefer to encode business logic in the app, and not depend on the limited features of FKs.